# How to remove an item in an array in Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am sending an object to Firebase which has an `ArrayList` of users. I need to delete a user from this array. How can I do to know the position of the user in this array and delete it?

```
"room" : {
    "-LswnaENRCSpJdB8-ZBg" : {
      "description" : "",
      "members" : [ {
        "id" : "jh4Ch9rBgQPwBTfv...",
        "name" : "John",
      }, {
        "id" : "5P6DzPIEuiSKU5UY...",
        "name" : "Jack",
      }, {
        "id" : "nKTlIyaDc3O3gxNp...",
        "name" : "Mary",
      } ],
      "name" : "MyRoom"
    },
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have the member you want to remove you can use `IndexOf` for finding the position of that member.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do to know the position of the user in this array and delete it?

There is currently no way you can create a query that can help you find a specific user that exists at a particular index in your `members` array.

To actually remove a particular user you'll need to load the entire `members` array, remove the user that you want client-side, and then write the entire array back.